# My App Crashes Everytime I Open It

Tags: java, android, xml, crash

Every time I try running my application, it crashes right away. It was working fine for the longest while, but it randomly broke, and I'm not sure what caused it. The only thing I could think of was that I uploaded a new jpg, and changed the background of something to it. But the thing is I tried changing the background back to the old thing it was, and I even tried deleting the jpg, so now I'm not sure what's wrong.

Here is my main activity's `onCreate()` function (the supposed root of the problem):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

And here's the stacktrace (sorry about the insane size):

```
08-03 14:59:36.516 4847-4847/ca.davesautoservice.davesautoservice E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ca.davesautoservice.davesautoservice, PID: 4847
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ca.davesautoservice.davesautoservice/ca.davesautoservice.davesautoservice.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at ca.davesautoservice.davesautoservice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at ca.davesautoservice.davesautoservice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:189)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:258)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:173)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:95)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at ca.davesautoservice.davesautoservice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:189) 
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:258) 
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:173) 
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:95) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at ca.davesautoservice.davesautoservice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
        at android.content.res.Reso
```

**Edit:** Here's the `activity_main` class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

If you need any additional info, I can surely give you some, just ask. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: `caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: Error is XML file :: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Comment: @DanielNugent What does this mean?

Comment: @RakshitNawani What's wrong with the NavigationView, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Well show your XML so that we can solve the error as soon as possible

Comment: @RakshitNawani I added the `activity_main` XML file, do you need another one too? I can give you the NavigationView's XML doc too?

Comment: I remember getting this issue. What I did was I created a new layout file from scratch and used that layout file.. and it started working automatically. Can you try it once. Don't copy paste write everything from scratch.

Comment: @pArAs Okay, I'll try it tomorrow, then post my results. Post it as an answer and I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: @pArAs I rewrote `activity_main.xml`, and it still crashes, should I rebuild the other related XML layouts and Java classes too?